# (Java) Learning try catch in a return method

Tags: java, exception, return, try-catch

So this is my code, I'm trying to learn try/catch in a return method. I want to catch an Exception in which the Hex String is not an even number, but my exception is not exactly executing the System.out.println("Hex String is invalid... etc"), and I can't remove the last second line which is return null; because it basically mean that if even it is not an even number it will still allow the method to run through. How do I prevent that from happening? Am I making any sense?

Basically, I don't want the method to go through if the perimeter not an even number!

```
    String hexString2 = "400000010";
    String hexString3 = "1A5E4567";

    System.out.println(toLittleEndian(hexString2));
```

> 

```
    public static String toLittleEndian(String hexString) {

    if (hexString.length() % 2 == 0) {
        try {

            String[] tempArr = new String[hexString.length() / 2];
            String result = "";
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
                String temp = "";
                temp += hexString.charAt(i);
                temp += hexString.charAt(i + 1);
                tempArr[count] = temp;
                System.out.println(tempArr[count]);
                count++;
            }

            for (int i = ((hexString.length() / 2) - 1); i >= 0; i -= 1) {
                result += tempArr[i];
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Hex String is invalid length! (Must be even number)");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: how about, not catching the Exception? The only way you can avoid this method to having to return a value or null, is by allowing it to throw an Exception

Comment: @Stultuske what do you mean? I've heard only of try/catch or throw exception, do you mean throw exception? thanks!!

Comment: I agree with @Stultuske. It means to remove the try/catch inside your method and add throws Exception.

 public static String toLittleEndian(String hexString) throws Exception { .. }

Then you need to handle or add a try/catch where you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have written if condition states as follows

```
if (hexString.length() % 2 == 0)
```

Not clear with your statement **Hex String is not an even number** while condition is other way around

- If you want length of hexString should be even then use code as follows.

> if (hexString.length() % 2 == 0){  ....... ...... }else{ throw new
>   Exception("Length is odd"); }

- If you want hexString should be even/odd then use code as follows.

> if (hexString % 2 == 0){  ....... ...... }else{ throw new
>   Exception("Length is odd"); }

**Throw new will throw exception to calli of method, but in case if condition wrapped inside try/catch block then exception will receive at respective catch.**

Answer (score 0):

The `try...catch` statement is used to *handle* exceptions - you have some code that might throw an exception, but that exception is not fatal and your program can still go on, this is where you use `try...catch`.

In your case however, it sounds like you want the program to stop executing immediately when the parameter is odd. Hopefully I have understood what you mean by "don't want the method to go through" correctly.

You should *throw* an exception here, which will stop your program if not handled by the caller:

```
public static String toLittleEndian(String hexString) {

    if (hexString.length() % 2 == 0) {

        String[] tempArr = new String[hexString.length() / 2];
        String result = "";
        int count = 0;
        ...

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Hex String is invalid length! (Must be even number)");
    }
}
```